# Azure Data Factory - lookup value to select statement in ForEach copy task

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow that is doing the following:

Setting date to today>Copy from API to temp table>Lookup ID in source table>Lookup ID in temp table against source table to only pass DeDupe values>ForEach for each ID that passes DeDupe validation>Copy task in ForEach that sequentially picks up each ID from the second lookup and store API data into Azure SQL.

I have all of my logic working, except the final task to use a select statement = to the ID of the DeDupe lookup:

[Overall data pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkIbO.png)

[ForEach value being passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS7JG.png)

[Copy task in ForEach picking up the current item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TpeI.png)

[Input for the copy task each sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijcys.png)

[Output for the copy task each sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti4An.png)

Notice in the last images, the input is generating the column name instead of just the value into the SQL statement. How do I prevent this, so I can pass just the value that's already defined in literals to the SQL statement? The idea here is to DeDupe values each run since this will be scripted to look into the future for reservation data.

Answer (score 0):

Add column name along with current item in copy activity like `@item().UID` and use **`concat()`** function to combine current item with string value as shown below.

**Output of lookup:**

[image]

**Copy data activity** source query inside ForEach activity:

`@concat('select * from tb1 where id = ',item().id)`

[image]

**Copy data Source Input:**

[image]